# How do I turn on syntax highlighting/coloring in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, settings

Basically, for whatever reason PyCharm's syntax highlighting/coloring just isn't working; all of the text just appears as plain black. This is despite the fact that according to my editor settings, under IDE Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General the highlighting/coloring does appear to be turned on and defined correctly. Can anyone tell me how to turn this on correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pycharm utils.py not getting syntax highlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374533/pycharm-utils-py-not-getting-syntax-highlight)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Checkout Settings | File Types. Probably the extension of file you need to be highlighted registered as Text file.

Answer (score 8):

Also advanced syntax highlighting/code inspections can appear to be broken but you will have to turn off power save to get them back :)

File>Power Save Mode