# Pycharm utils.py not getting syntax highlight

Tags: syntax-highlighting, pycharm

I have several django projects and several different files with name `utils.py`, however pycharm treats them as simple `.txt` files with no syntax highlighting or any other kind of parsing, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Please see `File` | `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | **File Types**.

Look for your file name mapped to the **Text** type or to the **Auto-detect file type by content** type.

Remove the incorrect mapping and it will fix the issue.

If you still can't find the wrong mapping in the IDE settings, locate the `options/filetypes.xml` file in the [Configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory). Close the IDE and either edit this file to remove the incorrect mapping or delete this file to reset all the file types to the defaults.

[image: text files]

- You can also use [Revert File Type Override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlLo4.png) / [Override File Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvcDd.png) file context menu actions.

Comment: the pattern there is
    CVS;SCCS;RCS;rcs;.DS_Store;.svn;.pyc;.pyo;*.pyc;*.pyo;.git;*.hprof;_svn;.hg;*.lib;*~;__pycache__;.bundle;*.rbc;*$py.class; 

however utils.py was registered under Text file pattern , removed it.

Comment: This is generalizable to other file types getting associated with the wrong extension as well.  I had the same problem with one of my .js files getting associated with the plain text file type and this solution fixed my problem.

Comment: Ran into this accident today. Thought the filename extension would normally pickup the "Python Type" from the file-association choices, but I must of accidentally type the filename in the type Textfield.

Comment: PHPStorm also has this issue - adding this here to hopefully help future googlers.

Comment: Per @Nicolas's soon-to-be-deleted comment-as-answer: "In Pycharm 4.5, the `File Type` menu is in `Pycharm` | `Preferences` | `Editor`"

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. But this thread has been going on for years at Jetbrains, a right-click "change file association" would be nice :-0 https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206237949-Change-file-association-manually

Comment: I can't find the text files. In the File types there is a list of all the Recognised File types and in the list there is TEXT but not Textfiles. In Text i can't find any utils.py.
i am using mac and intelliJ

Comment: @MalickUsman Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I was having this problem for Grials JSON Views, `.gson` files. I couldn't find it via the UI, but I was able to find the association in the IDE settings file `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/<product><version>/options/filetypes.xml`. I deleted the incorrect entries and restarted the IDE, and it was back to normal. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As CrazyCoder answered, my file also landed in an unintended association. In my case it was "Auto-detect file type by content". You can just try to add your file to the desired file type (e.g. Python) and PyCharm will automatically try to move the association.

Comment: How would the OP do this within PyCharm?

Answer (score 2):

FYI, a quick action to reassociate a file's type will be available in the context menu of the Project tool window in **IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2** (EAPs should be available publicly around May 2021).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to right click the file in question (a django migration) and select `Mark as Python`.
I probably clicked `Mark as Plain Text` before by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this by going to the **Project** section , and then clicking **Override File Type**  by right clicking on the specific file. Then I selected the type of the file from the list of available file types.

That worked

Answer (score 0):

For me, the file somehow forgot its type. This can be overridden by

Right click the file name --> Override File Type --> Select file type.

[image]