# A PHP script file doesn't have PHP syntax formatting

Tags: phpstorm

In my PhpStorm, the file `index.php`, doesn't look like a PHP script, but a plain text file. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Settings | File Types | Text files**
- Find and remove **unwanted** pattern there -- I expect this to be `index.php` or very similar

Similar SO questions:

- [PHPStorm renders a particular file name as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614223/phpstorm-renders-a-particular-file-name-as-plain-text)
- [Pycharm utils.py not getting syntax highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374533/pycharm-utils-py-not-getting-syntax-highlight)

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this steps:**

Open PHPStorm settings by using `Ctrl+Alt+S`

1. In search box type **File types**
2. Select file types option from left side panel
3. Find `PHP Files (PHP)` from Recognized file types
4. Check for `.php` extension in below area (Registered Patterns). If not found add PHP.

[image]

Comment: `*.php`exsit,my question is only the file of `index.php` look like plain text ,the other file of php script is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on index.php and select "Mark as PHP".

(This option is there on PHPStorm 7.x, I'm not sure about 6.)

Comment: only get the option `Mark as Plain Text` in other php script. but right click on index.php , can't get the option

Comment: File marked as plain text this way will have slightly different file icon.