# JetBrains PhpStorm index.php file displayed as text file

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using JetBrains PhpStorm as my IDE, I absolutely love it but will sadly need to change to Adobe Dreamweaver because of one problem.

I have a rather annoying problem any `index.php` file gets **displayed as a text file** even though it has the extension `.php`. Note **this is only for files named `index.php`** I suppose this is a setting that needs to be changed but cant find any solution in the docs.

Anyone experienced same problem before...? Any help advice much appreciated.

*Below you can see a sample image*

[image]

Comment: It doesn't do this for me. My `index.php` has the PHP icon.

Comment: Whenever I've had problems with PhpStorm, JetBrains tech support has been very helpful. Why don't you contact them before switching.

Comment: Thank you I have contacted them via their website

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee The answer given is correct -- I should have more than 10 similar answers in my own history -- here is exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22709627/783119. The reason is `index.php` pattern is more precise than generic `*.php` hence first pone overrides 2nd. How you have created such pattern -- it's another story (most likely accidentally, without checking what's happening on the screen -- e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21281563/783119)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `File`-> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `File types` and check text files. There will be an added pattern (index.php). Just romove it.

Comment: Have you checked "Registered Patterns" under the text files? There might be a pattern like index.php?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee But it sounds like you have another entry that's overriding the general pattern for this filename.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem but the above suggestions weren't helpful.  I resorted to looking at my project files, and within .idea/misc.xml I found:

```
<component name="ProjectPlainTextFileTypeManager">
 <file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/path/to/myfile-c.php" />
</component>
```

Removing these lines fixes the problem.  If I were to have this problem again, where would I find the setting in the user interface?  It is apparently a project level override.  Using phpStorm 9.x on MacOS.