# Weird issue with PhpStorm and JS file

Tags: javascript, symfony, phpstorm

Hello and happy new year;

I have a weird issue related to a JS file that I created in my project.

I am working with PhpStorm and Symfony. When I create a JS file into the js folder, no matter what, if I name it "main.js" it will undoubtedly turn this file into a text file. Even though I choose to create a JavaScript file.

If I put any other name it will work fine.
To correct the problem I could easily change the name and that is it but this is a joint project and I cannot change it.

I was looking in PhpStorm settings but couldn't find any solution to it. Maybe I thought that here people would have encountered that kind of problem.

Here is the crime scene:

[image: Here is the crime scene]

Comment: I have the same problem with a `.php` extension

Comment: check this Link goto, it helped me :) I didn't see it while searching on stack, my research was not well targeted [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591003/how-can-i-change-the-file-type-association-of-an-existing-file-in-webstorm)

Answer (score 0):

Try right-click on it file and select `Mark as JavaScript`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't have the option "Mark as JavaScript" in the rolldown menu.