# how to turn on syntax highlighting for java in pycharm?

Tags: java, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting doesn't work for java files.

Anyone has any idea how to turn it on for java files?

Tried the solution in the link below but it still doesn't work.

[IntelliJ not recognizing a particular file correctly, instead its stuck as a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915202/intellij-not-recognizing-a-particular-file-correctly-instead-its-stuck-as-a-tex)

Comment: Use IntelliJ instead of PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternative solutions suggested here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206604905-Java-support-

1: Use IntelliJ Community Edition with a python plugin (corresponds to PyCharm Community Edition)

2: Use Community Edition of IntelliJ for the java part of a project (but not opening it as a project since that will make PyCharm and IntelliJ conflict)

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want syntax highlighting, this should already come out of the box for many languages by the bundled plugin [TextMate Bundles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tutorial-using-textmate-bundles.html). Java is one of the already included languages - others can be added via downloaded TextMate bundles.

If you don't have syntax highlighting for Java out of the box: make sure that the plugin is activated in the [plugin settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/plugins-settings.html) and that Java is activated in the TextMate bundles settings.