# IntelliJ is treating all my files as text files

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

1. I created a file with an invalid extension (.jjs) from my sticky keyboard.
2. I deleted this file
3. all the icons for all my files turn into text icons. I lose my colour-theming, no variables are highlight, everything is like a plain text file.

How do I fix this? I can't find anything in the help docs

[image]

I am currently running IntelliJ 2017.3.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ not recognizing a particular file correctly, instead its stuck as a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915202/intellij-not-recognizing-a-particular-file-correctly-instead-its-stuck-as-a-tex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by going to preferences -> editor -> file types -> text and removing "*.js". Then adding "*.js" under javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the directory marked as a source directory, hence it is not treated as a directory containing sources.

Either right click on the directory and then "mark directory as->sources root" or go into the module options and from the modules->sources tab mark the directory there.

Comment: I just resolved the problem. *.js was registered under text file file types.

Answer (score 0):

got to `file > project Strucutre` click on `modules` and tab `Sources` select the directory where is your sourceCode (here `src`) and mark as `Sources`
[image]