# How to solve java file mapped to not java file type text

Tags: java, intellij-idea, file-type

I wanted to add a java class to a project, but I did a mistake and added it as a text file. Then, I removed it and tried to add it again as a java class, but unfortunately it doesn't work anymore. And I get the following error:

```
Unable to parse template "Class" Error message: ABC.java mapped to not java file type text
```

As I searched, I faced some solutions like
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915202/intellij-not-recognizing-a-particular-file-correctly-instead-its-stuck-as-a-tex) but I can't find `File Type` under `Editor` or anything similar that I can change as suggested in the solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am using IntelliJ 2018.3.4.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/104891.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go on `File->Settings` and a dialog will open. In that dialog navigate on the left part to `Editor/File Types` and then you need to choose from the section `Recognized File Types` `Java Class` and remove from bottom section the problematic extension (note you have a small minus button on the right)

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html

Comment: Supplementary point, in my case, the name of my Java class being unrecognized was added to the "File name patterns" of "Recognized File Type": Text

Answer (score 6):

This is a variant of Markov's answer that worked in my scenario.

Try going to `File->Settings->Editor->File Types` and to the `Recognized File Types` tab. Click the `"Auto-detect file type by content"` choice, and delete the name of the file you are trying to create from the `"File Name Patterns"` section by using the minus button.

[image]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Best answer! In my case, it was `File type auto-detected by file content` and not "Auto-detect file type by content". I am on Android Studio (Dolphin) 2021.3.1 Patch 1.

Answer (score 4):

Select required file type in top list (Recognized File Types) -- do it for "Text files"
In bottom list (Registered Patterns) select undesired pattern -- "SomeFileName.java"
Click on "-" (Minus) button to remove pattern from the list
Repeat 1-2-3 for other undesired patterns

If desired, you can also do this manually by editing config file while IDE is closed. Because it's IDE-wide setting, it is not stored in .idea folder (which has project settinsg only) -- the file to look for is called filetypes.xml and shoudl be located in ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdeaXX/options ( see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181 for other OS etc )

Answer (score 0):

Certainly inelegant, but you can simply copy the contents of the file to the clipboard (ctrl-c or similar), delete the file (maybe make a temporary backup somewhere outside the project), then in IntelliJ go to the desired package, right click, select new, select Java Class, name it correctly, and then you can paste in the contents of your file (ctrl-v or similar).

Comment: As stated in the question he has tried that and it doesn't work. Doesn't work for me too.