# my IDE is shown as simple text editor. No colors and no auto-complete

Tags: intellij-idea

I tried everything written here.

- restart
- setting root folder
- checking power safe

But it was not solved

My screen does not show any color. Everything is white and black.
Control space is not working and there is no code completion.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve java file mapped to not java file type text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059826/how-to-solve-java-file-mapped-to-not-java-file-type-text)

Answer (score 1):

Check associations for "Text" in Preferences | Editor | File Types, if it contains  .java, remove it.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with Jetbrains Rider IDE, with vbhtml files.

Answer (score 0):

- File->Settings->Editor->Colors &Fonts and choose your scheme

or

- On IntelliJ press 'Ctrl Alt + S' [ press ctrl alt and S together], this will open 'Setting popup'
- In Search panel 'left top search 'Theme' keyword.
- In left panel itself you can see 'Appearance', click on this
- Right side panel you can see Theme: and drop down with following option

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p97TX.png)

Comment: They are already as you said. But it is not working.

Comment: Did you tried to change to an other Theme ore Scheme? If so I recommend to reinstalling it.