# A Python file is not properly detected and is missing syntax highlighting in Intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

I have configured python3 and added python3 as a facet to my project. However syntax highlighting still does not appear. I am on osx 10.8 and using Intellij Ultimate 12.1.4

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pycharm utils.py not getting syntax highlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374533/pycharm-utils-py-not-getting-syntax-highlight)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Preferences` | `File Types` and make sure `.py` extension is mapped to Python Files, also check that this specific file is not mapped to Text Files.

Comment: Which version / os are you on?  there is no Preferences top level menu item on IJ 12 on os x

Comment: Oh I see it is under Intellij | Preferences | File Types.  I am new to using IJ on OS X and the menu structure is different here.

Comment: Now I see it - yes the .py were mapped to text. So this is the correct answer.