# One of files in my project is not treated as Python code file by PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

It has a different icon and is shown with `Text` and `Data` tabs in the bottom. It seems somehow related to its name: `test_events.py`. Only if I name it this way, PyCharm exhibits this behavior. Using `text_eventz.py` is OK. How do I fix it?

Comment: Ugh, this might be one of those weird bugs that I run into with IntelliJ every now and then.  Did you create the file, then rename the file with a .py extension?

Comment: I might have started that way...

Comment: Create a new file called `test_something.py`, something like that.  Then create one called `text_something.py`.  If it still does the same thing with the "test" file, it could have something to do with a unittest plugin.  Some unittest modules specifically look for files starting with "test".

Comment: @paidhima any name but test_events.py works as expected.

Comment: Let's see if it can be recreated.  Create a file called "test_foo", then rename it to "test_foo.py", and see if it exhibits the same behavior as "test_events.py".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check Settings | Editor | File Types | Text | Registered patterns. This file name may have gotten mapped to the "Plain text" file type; if you remove the erroneous mapping, everything will start working correctly.

(This is a bug in PyCharm, but unfortunately we don't know the exact steps to reproduce it.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374533/pycharm-utils-py-not-getting-syntax-highlight