# IntelliJ IDEA does not recognize properties file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, properties-file, intellij-17

IntelliJ IDEA does not recognize my property file as seen in the picture below.

[image: Property file not recognized]

When I change the name to something other than **"assetInformationFields"** like "assetInformationField" it is recognized perfectly.

[image: Property file recognized]

I already tried to invalidate caches and restart. IntelliJ IDEA version: 2017.1.5

Comment: and when you chang it back to "assetInformationFields" from "assetInformationField" does it unrecognized it?

Comment: looks like a bug

Comment: Can you right-click the file and select "mark as Properties"?

Comment: How is this impacting you other than by displaying an uglier icon?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/104891. You have the same problem.

Comment: @GabiM I have no syntax highlighting or any other property file features.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Your comment solved the problem. Could you please answer the question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see `File` | `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | **File Types**, select the **Text files** and remove `assetInformationFields.properties` from there. Most likely it was added by accident from the file right click context menu.