# IntelliJ Community Edition not recognising properties file on application startup

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, properties

I have an application which when I try to run in intelliJ by runing the main method I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jwt.header' in value "${jwt.header}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236) ~[spring-core-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
```

When i build and run this project as a jar, it works fine, recognising the propertys file.
I am new to intelliJ after making the switch from eclipse. I have tried several things such as this: [Article1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014953/intellij-idea-does-not-recognize-properties-file) and this [Article2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954087/intellij-idea-complains-cannot-resolve-spring-boot-properties-but-they-work-fine) and this [Article3](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206998045-Unable-to-find-properties-file-at-runtime) but I have no luck.

Is there some settings I should know about to get intelliJ to recognise my property's file?
I have marked my resource folder as a source root as this contains my property's file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My colleague is able to run the project perfectly in the enterprise edition?

Thanks

Comment: How are you supplying value for `${jwt.header}`?

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by having `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$` set as the Working Directory for the applications run configuration. For any future readers, my working directory was set to  i.e `/home/workspace/project` rather than the `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$`. Not quite sure how this worked, but it has! I believe this is an internal intelliJ feature