# in Android studio Register New File Type Association for ttf

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm getting an error that " Error: Content is not allowed in prolog."

> I can not turn back "Register New File Type Association" Panel.

Then, Android studio runs to this[image]

nothing happens when I installed.The Problem still continues.

And I was clicked mistakenly "Open matching files in associated application" when Register New File Type Association panel was opened.
[image]

I looked up IntelliJ IDEA documentation but I can not found a solution.
Someone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: So, what's the problem? Opening .ttf in external application? Which behavior would you expect instead?

Comment: I click install when external application opened. nothing happens.the problem is that I told at the top of the question. the problem is "Error: Content is not allowed in prolog ". I selected the second option mistakenly and I can not turn back the  Register New File Type Association Panel.

Comment: You can remove .ttf from [the list here](https://i.imgur.com/8VRGITD.png). If it's mapped to a Text file, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/104891.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `.ttf` extension from [the list here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1oZf.png).

If it's mapped to a Text file type, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/104891).