# Can't understand the language of Scene Builder User interface

Tags: intellij-idea, scenebuilder

I recently installed Scene Builder to my Intellij i have no problems installing or running the scene builder through my fxml file but when i open it the words in the user interface is not set in English.

My JDK, JAVAFX are both version 11

i have already tried to change the font via intellij but it is still not going back to English, also tried to install and uninstall Scene Builder and Intellij too, also tried using JavaFx Scene Builder and Gluon Scene Builder same result.

I tried installing it in my main computer and it works perfectly

Here is the provided Image of what my interface looks like:

[image]

i expect the font or the language to be in english please help thank you

Comment: There is some issue with your system fonts and Java apps can't render the text properly, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/104891 for the similar problem. Changing the font for IntelliJ IDEA works, but not sure how to fix it for the Scene Builder.

Comment: Thank you for the idea the problem was not in the intelliJ IDEA fonts it was in my windows fonts i just deleted all the fonts and downloaded the default windows fonts from the net.

Comment: I can't figure out the problem can you help me i am using Mac

Comment: @MalickUsman see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266524

Comment: Thankyou i figured it out.

Comment: @MalickUsman any luck?