# Java Scene Builder not In English

Tags: java, scenebuilder

[image]

How do I switch Scene Builder to English? Did I download the wrong version of Java or is this something I can change in settings?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422568/cant-understand-the-language-of-scene-builder-user-interface

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(

Comment: It does not seem like problem is with Scene Builder (of course it is not). I saw this kind of "weird" symbols when i tried to run my jar application on some Mac (do not know model or version), are you using mac? Maybe try different JDK/JRE in your system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scene Builder Editor displaying weird characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65150438/scene-builder-editor-displaying-weird-characters)

Answer (score 0):

add the second line below right after you declare the Parent

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
root.setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'Times New Roman';");
```