# Unable to create classes with IntelliJ. As file > name mapped to not java file type 'Text'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij randomly is not letting me create classes.

When I left click and create class It gives the following message.

> **Cannot Create Class**
>
> Unable to parse template "Class" Error message: Selected class file
> name 'Second.java' mapped to not java file type 'Text'

If I click "OK" the file outputs the following:

```
package PACKAGE_NAME;public class Second {
}
```

I disabled TextMate Bundles and reenabled and now syntax is not color schemed.

I even deleted Intellij (put in trash and emptied) and reinstalled and the problem is still present.  Mac M1.

Additionally, I am unable to click the green run button.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/104891 for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that this file (or a pattern that represents it) is not listed under

Settings → Editor → File Types→ Text

*.java was listed as a text file

Settings → Editor → File Types→ Java

*.java was not listed.

Added back, *.java to file name patterns.