# IntelliJ IDEA can't import packages that are present under External Libraries

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Trying to help my colleague set up and we're stumped why IntelliJ cannot find packages it clearly downloaded and sees (according to External Libraries).

[image]

Things he's tried:

- File > Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and Restart
- Right click on root pom.xml > Maven > Reload project
- mvn clean compile
- mvn clean install
- Switching Maven home path to bundled Maven (and back)
- Reload All Maven Projects on Maven tab

What else can we check or try?

Comment: Do these libraries belong to the module where you see the problem? What's the scope of these dependencies? Can you browse the jar files to see the actual classes that can't be imported (possible jar corruption)? Does the project build outside of the IDE using `mvn clean package`? Does it help if you delete `.idea` directory and [perform the clean import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start)? Are there any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) after importing the project?

Comment: Does Build | Sync tool window report any problems? Make sure `.class`/`.jar` and other important extensions were not remapped, inspect `options/filetypes.xml` file under the configuration directory, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/104891) for more details. Check that `.class`/`.jar` extensions are not ignored at File | Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | File Types, [Ignore files and folders](https://i.imgur.com/gwoSwTT.png).

Comment: Comment out lines in build gradle/pom xml, rebuild project and remove comments, rebuild again. If it helps, please, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called scope in pom.xml . By default the scope for the code we write in java files is considered as compile. Hence by modifying that scope in pom.xml dependencies are accessible now.
[scope tag in pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXq9O.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I was not able to import classes even though the jars were showing correctly under the External Libraries.

Open the **Project Structure** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) and then select **Modules** and verify the **Scope**. In my case the scope was set as **Runtime** and I was not able to import during Compile.

[image: Module settings]