# Intellij issue with "Command" groovy class

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, groovy

I have a grails domain class called "Command.groovy", which isn't being picked up by intellij as a domain class, for any and all purposes (such as highlighting that class or importing it in files, it says it's not found).

However, my code still compiles and works.

I tried looking online about this issue but haven't found anything about this.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/104891 helps. Make sure it's not present in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Auto Import | Exclude from auto-import and completion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @CrazyCoder, I found the answer where you mentioned.

The problem was the file was mapped to auto detect file type by content for some reason. (Found in settings->file types->Auto-detect file by content)