# how to fix intellij open .conf files?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the most recent update of IntelliJ IDEA community edition 2023.2.5
I have some scala projects and all the .conf files are showing white blocks icons, double click won't open them for edit.
These should be showing text files before.
I tried to override the file types back to plain text, then I can edit. But anyone knows how to make it editable without specific overrding?
[image]

Comment: It can be handled by some plug-in you installed. Can you share the screenshot of the icon and what it's mapped to in the File Types by default in your installation?

Comment: attached screengrab.

Comment: With the default settings, it's recognized as the text file type. Any overrides in your `filetypes.xml` file? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/104891.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out from that link that I can solve it by adding the *.conf to the Text fileTypes

Answer (score 0):

While it should work out of the box with the default IntelliJ IDEA installation, a solution to such problems would be to associate the file with the Text file type:

Settings | Editor | File Types | Recognized File Types.